# Filter subpages in while loop from WP Query object

Tags: wp-query, loop

I'm looking to optimize a page where I'm using several queries (with WP Query) to retrieve similar data, and I'm considering merging these queries together  then filtering for relevant data once inside a loop.
In one of the loops I want to not display subpages even though they are fetched with the query. I'm thinking along the lines of this -

```
    $query = new WP_Query();

    $query->query( 'post_type=pages' );

    // Menu, need to remove subpages here
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    if (!is_page(the_post());
        $menu .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    endif; endwhile;
```

Not sure how to accurately use this statement though, any ideas?

Edit: Never mind, solved it using "if( $post->post_parent == 0) { }" after initiating the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could even try passing `'post_parent' => 0` to the query. In your case it would be

```
$query->query( 'post_type=pages&post_parent=0' );
```

Comment: I want to reuse the query, that's why I want to filter the subpages first inside the loop.